# How to get rid of the index column name in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

The column header used to be on the row index #2. When I converted the row to the header, number 2 is followed.

I haver tried reset_index and index.rename but they don't seem to get rid of number 2. Please help. Thanks!

| 2 | Date | Customer | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 10-Jan | Tony | Rubber |
| 4 | 10-Jan | Mary | Paper |
| 5 | 11-Jan | Jane | TV |

Comment: try ``df.rename_axis(columns=None)``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rename_axis()`. The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) state that you can use the method to rename axis columns or indexes. For your program, use:

```
df.rename_axis(columns=None)
```